# Bug Auth::check() when i check login

Tags: laravel

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');

    $customer = Customer::where('email', $email)->first();
    $user = User::where('email', $email)->first();
    dd(Auth::check(),$customer,$user);
```

}

I am creating a simple login controller but when I log in and dd Auth::check() it turns out false. I want to assign permissions but my logic is that one user has many permissions so I have 3 user tables user_role and role and I don't know how to handle it

Comment: Well, the user is not logged in YET ! start with [basics](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication) first

Comment: why dont you use ```Auth::attempt()``` ? like `Auth::attempt(['foo','bar'])` start with the basics as @PsyLogic suggested. It's better suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to add login functionality code. Todo that you can use the below code :

   Auth::attempt(['email','password']);
2. Once you can loggedin successfully. You can check that the user is loggedin or not by using :

   $isLoggedIn = Auth::check() ? true : false;
3. You can get the loggedin user details by using

   $user = Auth::user();

Now you can check the current user's role and assign that user to permission as per your requirement.

For the role and permission you can check the below laravel package which I guess simple and perfectly suits for your requirement :

```
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction
```